# Make button 200% bigger

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have YoutuTube button with counter on my website: www.lukas-tv.pl
I mean button under: "Prawie 200 000 sybrybcji!"

I'd like to make this button 200% bigger and center it. Could you help me?

Comment: There's a lot of info already online on how to do this

Comment: on `.apsc-theme-3 .apsc-each-profile` remove `float: left` and add `display: inline-block; transform: scale(2);`

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice solution. I recommend to you study a little bit of CSS.

```
.apsc-theme-3 .apsc-each-profile {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

Comment: Add `float: none;` to the styles I have provide you.